# what is "removing backup files" installation step

Tags: windows, installation

In many windows installers the last step is called "removing backup files".

I understand that to provide transactional integrity of the install process some "backup files" could've been created and have to be cleaned up.

What I do not understand is why on many occasions this step takes considerably longer than the rest of the installation.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Usually installers create a backup of the current files they are overriding encase the installer fails midway through (or someone cancels) so that they can do a roll back. As far as why it takes considerably longer, it really depends on your computer configuration.

Comment: I have seen it happening on many computers. besides, shouldn't it be more taxing to install new files (with all the template interpretation, validation, dependency processing, etc) than just removing the old files? regardless of the configuration?